# Whats wrong with my Aloe Vera plant how do I fix it?

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-health, aloe

I'm super new to this planting thing and really dont want my aloe to die! I got my *Aloe Vera* about a week ago and put it in the pot watered it and put it in my window it's now starting to turn brownish yellow at the tips. Before I wrote this it had some fake hey stuff around it that it came with and I watered through that know Im watering it with out it on. Was that the problem can someone please help me-jadyn a very new planter.

[image][image][image][image]

Answer (score 1):

Your aloe might be "sunburned". My aloe plants seem very intolerant of strong light and are happy getting little to no direct sunlight each day. Sometimes I've put them in an eastern or southern window, and they start losing their healthy green color like yours. But if I move them to a spot with plenty of indirect light, they green right up within a week or so.

Here's more discussion on aloe turning red due to excessive light: https://www.quora.com/Why-do-Aloe-vera-plants-turn-red

Good luck!